# error in class destructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory-leaks, destructor

I just started my container class and already I'm having issues:

```
class Container
{
    private:

    string* BasePointer; // The starting pointer.
    unsigned int Capacity; // The number of values the container can hold.

    public:

    Container() // Default constructor.
    {
        Capacity = 1;
        BasePointer = new string[Capacity];
    }

    ~Container() // Destructor.
    {
        delete BasePointer; // Delete the container to prevent memory leaking.
    }
};
```

I get the error `Container Classes(26467) malloc: *** error for object 0x100100088: pointer being freed was not allocated`.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It is called *destructor*, as in destruction. Not deconstructor. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `XXX ptr = new XXX[size]` should be matched with array version `delete [] ptr`, not just regular `delete`.

Read about [free store management](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt) in C++, and as James reminds us - follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) in cases like this.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking about

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a syntactical reason for the `[]`?  Can it contain an optional argument or something?

Comment: No, you must not supply an argument. And the reason is - well, what it does is different from what delete does, so it needs a different name ;)

Answer (score 4):

you must use delete[]

```
delete[] BasePointer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned that you have mismatched `new[]` with `delete` and you must change `delete` to `delete[]` to fix it.  However, this is just the first of your issues.

You also need to implement (or at least declare as private) the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  Otherwise, think about what happens when you do this:

```
{
    Container c1;
    Container c2(c1);
}   // c2.~Container(); // frees the memory pointed to by 'BasePointer'
    // c1.~Container(); // also frees the memory pointed to by 'BasePointer'.
```

Since the `BasePointer` member of both `c1` and `c2` points to the same array, it gets freed twice.

There are some easier-to-use alternatives:

- Consider using a `std::vector` anywhere you might otherwise use a dynamically allocated array.  Since your class is called `Container`, I assume you are attempting to implement a resource-owning container, so perhaps you don't want to use this.
- Consider using a `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` (if your compiler supports it) to manage ownership of the pointer.  Both of these suppress generation of the implicitly declared copy constructor, forcing you to implement your own if you actually attempt to use them.

Even though you are implementing a `Container`, you should still take advantage of more primitive containers to do the heavy lifting for you (or, at least reimplement those primitive containers so that the heavy lifting is consolidated into a small set of utilities).

Finally, as a stylistic point, you don't need to use `malloc` for a container.  The standard library provides `std::allocator` which can be used to allocate space for and construct objects.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you create array you must use delete []BasePointer;

Answer (score 0):

To be more explicit than the other ones - when you `new`-ed an array type, you need to delete the pointer using `delete[]`.

This doesn't only happen when you use `new T[size]`, consider the following sample:

```
typedef int T[42];
int* x = new T;
delete[] x; // needs delete[] though you used new without []
```

On a general note, if your object "owns" an object it holds via a pointer, you should consider using a smart pointer (like boost::scoped_array) for that. That way, you don't need to worry about deconstruction, what happens when an exception gets thrown, implementing assignment op and copy constructor ...